# (Beginner) SQLite Query won't enter if-loop with MoveToNext

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have been on StackOverflow all morning trying to teach myself how to do a query into my uploaded SQLite database on an Android Application. I have tried raw and direct queries, but neither have worked so far. Here is the code:

```
public Product getProduct(int id) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();


//        new String[] { COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME, COLUMN_SIZE, COLUMN_HP,
//        COLUMN_CATEGORY, COLUMN_POWER_TYPE, COLUMN_EXP_PROOF, COLUMN_RPM,
//                COLUMN_PSI, COLUMN_GPM, COLUMN_PRICE},

//        Cursor cursor = db.query(
//                TABLE_NAME,
//                null,
//                COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
//                new String[] { Integer.toString(id)},
//                null, null, null, null);

    String strquery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + "=" + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strquery, null);

    Product product = new Product();


    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        product.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
        product.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        product.setSize(cursor.getDouble(2));
        product.setHp(cursor.getDouble(3));
        product.setCategory(cursor.getString(4));
        product.setPowerType(cursor.getString(5));
        product.setExplosionProof(cursor.getInt(6));
        product.setRPM(cursor.getInt(7));
        product.setBypassPSI(cursor.getInt(8));
        product.setGPM(cursor.getInt(9));
        product.setPrice(cursor.getDouble(10));
        cursor.close();
    }

    db.close();
    return product;
}
```

The commented out fields are previous queries I tried, neither working.

And here are my constants:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Products";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "'_id'";
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YiZr.png
^ that is a link to a screenshot of the database I am using.

The issue when I debug it is it never enters the if loop, and mCount is always -1. I have done a lot of research, but I am still being frustrated with this. Thank you

[**EDIT**}

Here is my code to the database

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private SQLiteHelper sInstance;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ProductList.db";
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context myContext;
private String databasePath = "";


public SQLiteHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    databasePath = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();
}


private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Products";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "'_id'";
private static final String COLUMN_PRODUCT_NAME = "'Name'";
private static final String COLUMN_SIZE = "'Size'";
private static final String COLUMN_HP = "'HP'";
private static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "'Category'";
private static final String COLUMN_POWER_TYPE = "'PowerType'";
private static final String COLUMN_EXP_PROOF = "'ExpProof'";
private static final String COLUMN_RPM = "'RPM'";
private static final String COLUMN_PSI = "'PSI'";
private static final String COLUMN_GPM = "'GPM'";
private static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "'Price'";

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExists = checkDataBase();
    if (dbExists) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error making database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase check = null;
    try {
        String path = databasePath + DATABASE_NAME;
        check = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database doesn't exist
    }

    if (check != null) {
        check.close();
    }

    return check != null;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    String outFileName = databasePath + DATABASE_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // close streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}



public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = databasePath;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
```

}

Comment: Query looks good the only reason I can see why this doesn't work is that the table is empty. Are you sure you're opening the correct db?

Comment: @JamesBaltar can you take a look at my edit? That is how I am getting to the database

Comment: @llr7245 I prefere this tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm may this help you. Your methode is a litte awkward

Comment: @Developer66 does that work with android?

Comment: @llr7245 this also works with android

Comment: @llr7245 for android this is a good article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Comment: @Developer66 Thank you for your links!!

Answer (score 1):

Please review this part of your code.

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    //Open the database
    String myPath = databasePath;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}
```

Here you're just using `databasePath` and I see that you've set this to the value you've got from `context.getDabasePath` in the constructor but looking at the other methods you have they look like they're creating a new db path instead:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    String outFileName = databasePath + DATABASE_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // close streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Not sure if this is because of copy/paste from your source code but this looks like what is causing the missing data that you have.